# cryptsetup luksFormat error "Device /dev/nvme0n1p3 is in use. Can not proceed with format operation."

Tags: encryption, luks, home, disk-encryption, cryptsetup

I've followed [this guideline](https://feeding.cloud.geek.nz/posts/encrypting-your-home-directory-using/) to the point where I encrypt the target partition:

```
cryptsetup -h sha256 -c aes-xts-plain64 -s 512 luksFormat /dev/nvme0n1p3
```

Then, the error appears, even though I'd unmounted the home partition previously like so:
umount -l /home

The reason for the *-l*-flag was that it didn't work without it. Moreover, in order to get so far, I had to boot my system till reaching the user-login screen, then press `CTRL+ALT+F2` to get into `tty2`, there log into my user via "login" and "password", then unmount the "/home" - partition forcefully.

Even though I'd checked previously via gparted which is the mount-point on the hard-drive related to /home, it states

> "Device /dev/nvme0n1p3 is in use. Can not proceed with format
> operation."

albeit having unmounted "/home" previously.

How can I finish encrypting my "/home" - partition with LUKS (cryptsetup)? Could I use this in the same way to encrypt my swap, /temp, and /var/temp as well, since I couldn't encrypt the entire ubuntu 20.04 installation due to being installed in parallel to Windows 10?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`umount -l` is so called *lazy* unmount -- for busy filesystems this waits until the filesystem is no longer in use before really unmounting it.

From `mount` manpage:

> **-l, --lazy**
>
> Lazy unmount.  Detach the filesystem from the file hierarchy now, and clean up all references to this filesystem as soon
> as it is not busy anymore.

So the `cryptsetup` call failed because your `/home` is still in use and it is used because you are logged in. You need to logout first and then unmount your `/home`. For that you'll need to either login as root (which doesn't use `/home`) or use LiveCD.

Yes you can use the same steps to encrypt your swap (this can be done from running system after `swapoff -a` to disable swap) and other partitions.

Btw. if you want to encrypt your entire system, I'd recommend using [LVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_%28Linux%29) which allows you to setup the encryption on a single point on the physical volume layer (but that would require reinstalling your system).

Comment: Thanks. Could you please elaborate further on how I login as root in tty? I assume that I'd have to type "root" as "login", but then it'll ask me for a password and that one won't be the same as for my personal-user for sure. Moreover, I can't think of any password that I'd defined apart from the user-specific root. In short, I have no clue how to login as "root" if I'm not already logged into my user. The only thing I know is that, when logged in as user, you can use `sudo` and similar commands to carry out operations as root.

Comment: I assume you are using Ubuntu. `root` account is by default locked and you need to set password for it first: https://askubuntu.com/questions/44418/how-to-enable-root-login